# Highcharts.js - manually render a single pie

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Can I do that?

From the *documentation*, you can format the "dataLabels" by passing in a function. I would like to gain the same control for colorizing a single *pie* from a PieChart.

I know I can pass in an Array of colors, but I don't want Highcharts to just automatically set these colors values, I want to set the color based on the value for a pie/area.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the color for each slice as follows. Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/a86By/).

```
            data: [
                    {
                        name: 'A',
                        y: 1,
                        sliced: true,
                        selected: true,
                        color: getColor(1)
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'B',
                        y: 12.8,
                        sliced: false,
                        selected: false,
                        color: getColor(12.8)
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'C',
                        y: 52.8,
                        sliced: false,
                        selected: false,
                        color: getColor(52.8)
                    }
                ]
```

Just set the color on each point according to it's value.

Also, you can dynamically update the colors, e.g.

```
function updateChart() {
    chart.series[0].data[1].update({
        color: '#ff0'
    });
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, that is not dynamic. I can't dedice "in-code" what and when to do, reacting on a value. Thats just hardcoded.

Comment: @AndreMeinhold Are you serious?! To apply color **when** you want - you can use `chart.events`, `series.events` and `point.events`. To do **what** you want - write your own function that will handle all color manipulations.

Comment: @IgorShastin: there is an event like `point.render` ? If thats the case create an answer and you got it. But I didn't find any event that  would allow to initially set the color of pies. I'm not looking for mouseover events

Comment: @AndreMeinhold Maybe I don't get it - what's wrong with the Greg's answer? He made an example which allows you to *initially set the color of pies*.

Comment: @IgorShastin: with the current answer, he hardcodes the values into the pies. Thats not why I was asking for. I need to change value intensity, based on the VALUE. With this answer, you can't access the `value` data for a pie. If that would be the case, its what I'm looking for

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle and answer to dynamically update the point color. You can write your own function to determine the color based up value or anything else.